# ClassCastException in Spring IntegrationFlow Implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I currently have an IntegrationFlow implementation that utilizes a Service class to implement all desired functionality to be performed by the flow. Something like this...

```
@Service
public class FlowService {

    public Message<String> removeLineFeeds(Message<String> message) {
        return MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(StringUtils.remove(message.getPayload(), StringUtils.LF))
                .copyHeadersIfAbsent(message.getHeaders())
                .build();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class FlowConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private FlowService flowService;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("inputChannel")
                .transform(flowService, "removeLineFeeds")
                .get();
    }
}
```

The above implementation works exactly as desired but I was hoping to improve/modify the implementation to utilize the power of Java 8/Lambdas so that it looked something like this...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("inputChannel")
            .transform(flowService::removeLineFeeds)
            .get();
}
```

Unfortunately, when implemented this way, the flow will throw a `ClassCastException` whenever it processes a message. I have tried a few of the different proposed solutions that exist online currently but none of them seem to do the trick. I am encountering a similar issue regardless of the IntegrationFlow method used (transform, filter, etc.).

What needs to be changed with the current implementation to allow the use of `flowService::removeLineFeeds` within the IntegrationFlow methods?

**EDIT: PER ARTEM'S RESPONSE**

It appears a simple converter in the IntegrationFlow did the trick. My current implementation seemed to be passing the message as a `Message<byte[]>` instead of the `Message<String>` I was expecting. See Artem's full response below for more details.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("inputChannel")
            .convert(String.class)
            .transform(flowService::removeLineFeeds)
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that lambda must correspond to some functional interface. 
In case of `transform()` it is a `GenericTransformer<S, T>`. Indeed your `Message<String> removeLineFeeds(Message<String> message)` satisfies such a contract. And it would work well if you deal with only payload:

```
public String removeLineFeeds(String message) {
    return StringUtils.remove(message.getPayload(), StringUtils.LF);
}
```

Just because when all the generic information from the target implementation is erased at runtime we can't guess you would like to deal with the whole `Message<?>`, so the framework only propagates to your lambda only a payload. That how your `String` cannot be cast to `Message`, therefore a `ClassCastException`.

To fix the problem and mock Java generics system we suggest an overloaded method with an explicit expected type:

```
/**
 * Populate the {@link MessageTransformingHandler} instance for the provided
 * {@link GenericTransformer} for the specific {@code payloadType} to convert at
 * runtime.
 * @param payloadType the {@link Class} for expected payload type. It can also be
 * {@code Message.class} if you wish to access the entire message in the transformer.
 * Conversion to this type will be attempted, if necessary.
 * @param genericTransformer the {@link GenericTransformer} to populate.
 * @param <P> the payload type - 'transform from' or {@code Message.class}.
 * @param <T> the target type - 'transform to'.
 * @return the current {@link BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 * @see MethodInvokingTransformer
 * @see LambdaMessageProcessor
 */
public <P, T> B transform(Class<P> payloadType, GenericTransformer<P, T> genericTransformer) {
```

So, your configuration should look like this:

```
.transform(Message.class, flowService::removeLineFeeds)
```

This way we say the framework that we would like to get a whole message for our function to process.

Anyway I'd prefer the first variant just with a `payload`: the framework will take care for you about coping request headers into a reply message.

See more info in Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-class-cast

Comment: Thanks for the response Artem. I tried both of the solutions you suggested above but still encountered the ClassCastException. More specifically, the exception is now reading ```java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String```.

Comment: Well, that's already a different one, business related. You expect a `String`, but your message contains a `byte[]` as a payload. You can create a string from that `byte[]` in your transformer method, or use `convert(String.class)` and register a `Converter<byte[], String>` `@IntegrationConverter` bean.

Comment: Looks like adding the .convert(String.class) did the trick. Am I correct in assuming that when I had ```.transform(flowService, "removeLineFeeds")``` Spring Integration was handling the conversion for me? Trying to understand how I didn't encounter this issue in my original implementation.

Comment: That's correct. Because calling by method name lands in the reflection where we really can try to convert incoming data to expected type. With a lambda we have only a direct call and no one ca guess the target type for conversion, unless you use that overloaded method with `Class`...